# My parameter that I set inside the top_n for ggplot2 is not working?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I want to limit my graph to just the top 10 words (doing sentiment analysis) to graph. My parameter that I set is not working. Here is my code:

```
df_boatstone_bing  %>%
    group_by(sentiment) %>%
    top_n(10) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(word = reorder(word, n)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(word, n, fill = sentiment)) +
    geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
    facet_wrap(~sentiment, scales = "free_y") +
    labs(y = "Contribution to sentiment",
         x = NULL) +
    coord_flip()
```

If anyone can catch my mistake that would be great!

Edit: dput included

```
structure(list(word = c("awesome", "loud", "worth", "amazing", 
"excellent", "nice"), n = c(38L, 33L, 29L, 28L, 26L, 22L), sentiment = c("positive", 
"negative", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive"), 
 method = c("Bing et al.", "Bing et al.", "Bing et al.", "Bing et al.", 
"Bing et al.", "Bing et al.")), .Names = c("word", "n", "sentiment", 
"method"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: please post `dput(head(df_boatstone_bing))` to your question so that someone can use the data to reproduce your error

Comment: `top_n` without explicit column variable uses the *last* variable in your `tibble` for ordering. Is that the correct variable based on which you'd like to select the top 10 rows?

Comment: @MauritsEvers No it isn't. I included the data structure in the edit. But basically, there is a count for positive and negative sentiments. I want the top 10 positive sentiments graphed (ranked by the number of occurrences of that sentiment) and the top 10 negative sentiment respectfully.

Comment: @rmahesh Well, in that case does replacing the `top_n` command with `top_n(10, n)` do what you're after? As I explain, you may need to specify the column according to which you'd like to select the top 10 entries.

Comment: Everything looks fine except you should use `top_n(10, n)` as @MauritsEvers suggested, and your input dataset needs to be bigger. Your example only has one negative word.    When I feed my own larger fake data into your graph it looks good.      `library(tidytext)
set.seed(42)
df_bing_sample <- tidytext::sentiments %>%
  filter(lexicon == "bing") %>%
  sample_n(50) %>%
  mutate(n = rnorm(50, 30, 10) %>% floor %>% as.integer()) %>%
  mutate(method = "Bing et al.") %>%
  select(word, n, sentiment, method)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we specify `n` in the `top_n(word, n)` term, and have enough words in our input data, it should work fine.

```
# OP's 
df_bing_sample  %>%
  group_by(sentiment) %>%
  top_n(10, n) %>%   # <--- specify sort by n, rather than by method, the last column
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(word = reorder(word, n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(word, n, fill = sentiment)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~sentiment, scales = "free_y") +
  labs(y = "Contribution to sentiment",
       x = NULL) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Sample fake data here with more than 10 each of positive & negative:

```
library(tidytext)
set.seed(42)
df_bing_sample <- tidytext::sentiments %>%
  filter(lexicon == "bing") %>%
  sample_n(50) %>%
  mutate(n = rnorm(50, 30, 10) %>% floor %>% as.integer()) %>%
  mutate(method = "Bing et al.") %>%
  select(word, n, sentiment, method)
```